# Odata PATCH logic

Tags: java, odata

In OData: 
    `PATCH /Packages{id}` is going to overridden method `updateEntity()` of `SingleOdataProcessor`. But `PATCH /Package{id}/Path{id}` is not going to the respective overridden `updateEntity()` method.

Below is the error that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code></code>
<message xml:lang="en-US">The request is not supported by the processor.</message>
</error>
```

Comment: I don't think, PATCH supports anything passed `...{id}\`.

Comment: It does. Just that its not supporting an appended path

Comment: `PATCH /Package{id}` <-- legal | illegal --> `Path{id}`. But you can add child record to json in body